# Upvote count using Counter cache in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using counter_cache for counting the votes. A user can able to do one upvote and downvote.

My model

vote.rb

```
attr_accessible :celebrity_id, :user_id, :vote_dvote
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :celebrity, counter_cache: true
```

celebrity.rb

```
attr_accessible :name, :gender, :category_id, :votes_count  
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :category
has_many :votes

def total_upvotes
    Vote.where('vote_dvote = ?', true).count
end

def percentage_of_votes
    (self.votes_count.to_f / self.total_upvotes.to_f * 100.0).round(2)
end
```

Controller

```
def show_ranking              
  @celebrities = Celebrity.includes(:category).order(votes_count: :desc)      
  @celebrities.each do |celeb|
    celeb["votes_count"] = celeb.percentage_of_votes                
  end
end
```

both upvote and downvote saved in votes table, for upvote 'vote_dvote=1'and for downvote 'vote_dvote=0', votes_count for each celebrity is saved in celebrities table. what happening in my case is votes count is more than the total upvote count. So I can't able to get the exact percentage.

But I need only upvote count.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem in the past and spent a lot of time finding out whether counter_cache can do something like that, but found nothing. I would like to find out if someone got a cleaner solution, but what I do in my project is use a custom method that does what counter_cache is supposed to do, which I call "indexify!" for some reason.
In your case it would look like this. Migrate two columns :upvotes_count and :downvotes_count for celebrity table, and then:

celebrity.rb

```
# before_save :indexify! # only needed in certain cases

def indexify!
  self.downvotes_count = self.votes.where(vote_dvote: true)
  self.votes_count = self.votes.where(vote_dvote: false) 
end
```

vote.rb

```
after_save :indexify!

def indexify!
  self.celebrity.save!
end
```

and then once, either per migration or per console, reset the counters

```
Celebrity.all.each(&:save!)
```

I never had any problems with that solution, but I am still wondering if there is anything generic that Rails offers.

Comment: but  the upvotes and downvotes are not inserted in celebrity table, do I need to do anything other than this

Comment: Classic counter_cache also relies on votes_count already inserted into the celebrities table. I simply described the behavior of what counter_cache would actually do if it could work with upvotes_count or downvotes_count.

Comment: Another option I am currently working on for my project is using Redis as a cache to store calculated data such as this, so that, in your example, the last number of upvotes for a celebrity would be cached until another upvotes is created, when the number needs to be recalculated.